# Vue JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I have used v-model in my input field but it gives error of preventDefault of undefined. What am I missing here?

I have following code on my AddUser component.

```
<template>
    <form @submit="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-btn form-group text-center">
            <Button type="submit" text="Add" color="#2BA0A3" />
        </div>        
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import Button from './Button'
export default {
    name: 'AddUser',
    data(){
        return {
            name: ''
        }
    },
    components: {
        Button
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(e){ 
            e.preventDefault()
            if(!this.name){
                alert('Please enter name.')
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

@submit="onSubmit" instead of @submit="onSubmit()"

i think it will solve the issue.